# Comparing multiple multivariate datasets

Tags: time-series, statistics, normalization, multivariate-distribution

Take the two datasets below:

| default rate | state | age | income | asofdate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | Texas | 55 | 100,000 | 202309 |
| 14 | Texas | 35 | 97,000 | 202309 |
| 18 | Texas | 55 | 95,000 | 202308 |
| 22 | Texas | 35 | 95,000 | 202308 |
| 8 | New York | 21 | 55,000 | 202309 |
| 12 | New York | 40 | 55,000 | 202309 |
| 16 | New York | 21 | 65,000 | 202308 |
| 20 | New York | 40 | 65,000 | 202308 |

What I want to do, is compare the default rate of each state over time. I know that I could just compare the default rates across states when the conditions fall into the same bucket.

For example, the default rate in 202309 of Texas vs California, when age is 50-55, income is 55k-65k.

However, in the actual dataset, there are more columns and the buckets/groupings are much more granular quickly making the dataset very large if I was just to compare bucket by bucket.

Is there anyway I can normalize my dataset, so that I can make a fair comparison?